# Ruby Mixin module not saving Active Record property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, mixins

I have a eBook resource with a value property:

```
class EBook < ApplicationRecord
  include Mixin
end
```

and a module:

```
module Mixin
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    # validations
    belongs_to :user
  end
  def change_value
    @value = 200
  end
end
```

I would like to be able to call `EBook.change_value` and have that instance's value set to `200`. How can I do this? Is this an antipattern? I can't seem to find anything that will allow me to change instance state through a module.

Using the rails console I get this output:

```
  EBook Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `e_books`.* FROM `e_books` ORDER BY `e_books`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
 => 200
```

but it doesn't update or save the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord does not use separate instance variables for attributes represented in database.

Change your method to

```
def change_value
  self.value = 200
end
```

in order to use setter method generated by ActiveRecord for your model.

In order to clear it up a bit more, this is what your code did:

```
class Ebook < ApplicationRecord
  attr_reader :value

  def change_value
    @value = 200
  end
end

2.5.1 :001 > e = Ebook.new
 => #<Ebook id: nil, value: nil> 
2.5.1 :002 > e.change_value      # this sets your instance_variable
 => 200 
2.5.1 :003 > e
 => #<Ebook id: nil, value: nil> # ActiveRecord's value remain nil
2.5.1 :004 > e.value             # reads from instance variable as we've overwritten the method with attr_reader
 => 200 
2.5.1 :005 > e.read_attribute(:value) # reads from ActiveRecord's attributes
 => nil 
2.5.1 :006 > e.tap(&:save)
 => #<Ebook id: 3, value: nil>   # as expected, nothing is saved
```

Comment: Using self.value = 200 still doesnt seem to change the value. Even setting the value explicity like `EBook.first.value = 200` doesn't seem to change the underlying model, do you know why this is?

Comment: Are you saving the object? If you want your method to actually update the value in the database, use `update(value: 200)` instead.

Comment: No it appears as though I'm not, sorry about that!